# Magento observer get custom price

Tags: php, magento

I use the code below for changing the price into the Magento cart dynamic.

```
class Test_Pricecalc_Model_Observer
{
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
    {
        // Get the quote item
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

        // Load the custom price
        $price = $this->_getPriceByItem($item);
        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }

    protected function _getPriceByItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
    {
        $price = $price + 10;
        return $price;
    }

    protected function _getRequest()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getRequest();
    }
}
```

Does someone now how to get the custom price from the product detail page after choosing the product options there? I want to use that price as basis price fur my further calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hidden input field in product detail page with value equal to your custom price.
and can get that field in your observer like:

```
  $new_price = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('custom_price');
```

where 'custom_price' is the name of your hidden field and $new_price in oberserver is your custom price.

here is an example, which we used to render our product price during "add to cart":-

```
class Tech9_Myprice_Model_Observer 
{
public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
{
     // Get the quote item
   $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
   // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
   $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
   // Load the custom price


     $new_price = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('custom_price');
      Mage::log( $new_price);
   $price = $new_price;
   // Set the custom price
   $item->setCustomPrice($price);
   $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
   // Enable super mode on the product.
   $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);       
 }
}
```

Here **Tech9** is the name of our package and **Myprice** is the name of our module.

We had to use our custom price during "add to cart" event. We prepared a separate module for it , if you like we can provide you with that package as well.